# L'expression "que ci, que ça" existe-t-elle?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, argot

Je discutais avec ma sœur, qui parle un peu le français, et elle m'a demandé ce que voulait dire "comme ci, comme ça" en anglais. Je lui ai répondu que l'expression correspondait à la phrase "so-so" en anglais. Il y a plein de [synonymes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_ci_comme_%C3%A7a)!

Puis, je lui ai dit qu'on pouvait aussi dire "que ci, que ça" comme raccourci, mais quand j'ai mis cette phrase-là [dans Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=que%20ci%20que%20%C3%A7a&client=firefox-b-d&ei=JMmIYo_nLJjQgQbmhIPYBQ&ved=0ahUKEwiPidP5uvD3AhUYaMAKHWbCAFsQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=que%20ci%20que%20%C3%A7a&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEBMyDAgAEB4QDxAIEAcQEzoHCAAQRxCwAzoICAAQHhAIEAc6CggAEB4QDxAIEAc6BggAEB4QCDoICAAQHhAPEAg6BAgAEA06BggAEB4QBzoICAAQHhAIEA1KBAhBGABKBAhGGABQqghYkTFg_jhoAXABeACAATeIAbIDkgECMTCYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz), j'ai reçu des liens pour:

- [Comme ci, comme ça](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_ci_comme_%C3%A7a)
- [Qu'est-ce-que c'est que ça?](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/quece-que-ci-que-%C3%A7a.195372/)
- [Que ça](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/que+%C3%A7a)

**Mais**, la phrase exacte ("**que ci, que ça**") n'est pas apparue dans les résultats de ma recherche!

Comme ça fait plus de vingt-cinq ans que je ne parle plus quotidiennement la douce langue de Molière, je voulais savoir:

- si l'expression "que ci, que ça" existe encore? Et puis, si elle existe,
- la phrase s'écrit-t-elle bien comme cela?

Merci d'avance de vos réponses, et si j'ai fait des fautes de français, je vous prie de bien vouloir les corriger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je n'ai jamais entendu ou lu l'expression ***que ci, que ça*** et soupçonne que tu la confonds avec l'expression très proche phonétiquement *[**couci-couça**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couci-cou%C3%A7a)*. Cette dernière est toujours employée et a le même sens que ***comme ci, comme ça***.

Comment: J'en étais sûr - je l'avais bien entendue, cette expression là! C'est la façon de l'écrire qui m'échappait! Merci!

Answer (score 0):

`Que ci, que ça` n'existe pas, on peut utiliser `comme ci, comme ça`, qui signifie `ni bien, ni mauvais` (entre les deux, bof bof).

> Comment vas-tu ce matin?
> comme ci,comme ça (c'est à dire en moyenne forme)